# how can I put 2 files with the same number of lines side by side with Perl

Tags: perl

how can I put 2 files A and B with the same number of lines side by side with Perl with
command line ? I cannot work with two filehandles on the command line.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on what your trying to do. It sounds like this might be homework.

Comment: Read the first file into e.g. a list of lines, then read the second file into e.g. a list of lines and then print each "matching" element from each list one after the other e.g. `list1-1 list2-1` (side-by-side)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to go:

I used those 2 files:

```
$ cat file1
file1 line1
file1 line2
file1 line3

$ cat file2
file2 line1
file2 line2
file2 line3
```

Running one-liner:

```
$ perl -E '($f1,$f2)=@ARGV;open $F1,$f1;chomp(@l1=<$F1>);open $F2,$f2;chomp(@l2=<$F2>);for($i=0;$i<@l1;$i++){say $l1[$i],"\t",$l2[$i]}' file1 file2
file1 line1     file2 line1
file1 line2     file2 line2
file1 line3     file2 line3
```

```perl
($f1,$f2)=@ARGV;                # retrieve the 2 filenames
open $F1,$f1;                   # open first file
chomp(@l1=<$F1>);               # read it in an array
open $F2,$f2;                   # open second file
chomp(@l2=<$F2>);               # read it in an array
for($i=0;$i<@l1;$i++){          # loop thru all record (as said in question the 2 file have same number of records
    say $l1[$i],"\t",$l2[$i]        # print line by line the 2 file content separated by a tabulation
}
```